# spark-submit python file ‘home/.python-eggs’ permission denied

Tags: python, apache-spark

I had a problem when I use spark-submit to run a python file.When the 'map' code run in 'executor', the problem like this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py", line 151, in _run_module_as_main
  mod_name, loader, code, fname = _get_module_details(mod_name)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py", line 101, in _get_module_details
  loader = get_loader(mod_name)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pkgutil.py", line 464, in get_loader
  return find_loader(fullname)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pkgutil.py", line 474, in find_loader
  for importer in iter_importers(fullname):
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pkgutil.py", line 430, in iter_importers
  __import__(pkg)
File "/data8/yarn/local-dir/usercache/bo.feng/appcache/application_1448854352032_70810/container_1448854352032_70810_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
File "/data8/yarn/local-dir/usercache/bo.feng/appcache/application_1448854352032_70810/container_1448854352032_70810_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 35, in <module>
File "/data8/yarn/local-dir/usercache/bo.feng/appcache/application_1448854352032_70810/container_1448854352032_70810_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 51, in <module>
File "/data8/yarn/local-dir/usercache/bo.feng/appcache/application_1448854352032_70810/container_1448854352032_70810_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/shuffle.py", line 33, in <module>
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/psutil/__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/psutil/_pslinux.py", line 24, in <module>
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/_psutil_linux.py", line 7, in <module>
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/_psutil_linux.py", line 4, in __bootstrap__
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 945, in resource_filename
  self, resource_name
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1633, in get_resource_filename
  self._extract_resource(manager, self._eager_to_zip(name))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1661, in _extract_resource
  self.egg_name, self._parts(zip_path)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1025, in get_cache_path
  self.extraction_error()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 991,     inextraction_error
  raise err
  pkg_resources.ExtractionError: Can't extract file(s) to egg cache
  The following error occurred while trying to extract file(s) to the Python egg
  cache:
    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.python-eggs' 
  The Python egg cache directory is currently set to:  
   /home/.python-eggs  
 Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  You can
 change the cache directory by setting the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment
 variable to point to an accessible directory.
```

I set the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment variable to every executor,and I also write 'os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = "/tmp/"' in my program,but the problem is  still happen.

My code :

```
import os,sys
print "env::::"+os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE']
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
# Load and parse the data
def parsePoint(line):
    import os
    print "env::::"+os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE']
    os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = "/tmp/"
    values = [float(x) for x in line.split(' ')]
    return line

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = "/tmp/"
    print "env::::"+os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE']
    conf = SparkConf()
    sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
    data = sc.textFile(sys.argv[1])
    parsedData = data.map(parsePoint)
    parsedData.collect()
```

I run this python program in 'standalone' model and succeeded.
This is my submit command:

```
spark-submit --name test_py --master yarn-client testpy.py input/sample_svm_data.txt
```

Is the yarn's problem?

Comment: I use hadoop-streaming submit a python task and succeeded ,so yarn is fine executing python.

Answer (score 4):

This is late, but it's the first result @ google I found with this problem... the previous answer is helpful (i wanted to know which env vars I had to modify), but please DONT modify editing Spark sources, just change environment variables using the proper tools, add this to your spark.conf variables...

```
spark.executorEnv.PYTHON_EGG_CACHE="./.python-eggs/"
spark.executorEnv.PYTHON_EGG_DIR="./.python-eggs/"
spark.driverEnv.PYTHON_EGG_CACHE="./.python-eggs/"
spark.driverEnv.PYTHON_EGG_DIR="./.python-eggs/"
```

(I prefer not to use /tmp/ because . will get deleted after my job ends, so eggs should disappear too IMO)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem：
 unzip the pyspark.zip then find rdd.py file
 open this file , under "import os" line ,add code as :

```
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/tmp/.python-eggs/'
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_DIR']='/tmp/.python-eggs/'
```

save file and zip pyspark

Comment: Adding this to the `__init__` file of the package and generating the egg again worked for me. The other solutions didn't, although i could see that the conf parameters had been updated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with the help from BiS's answer. By adding the four configuration values when running spark-submit, it fixed the egg problem.

Here's an example of what adding the four parameters looks like when using spark-submit.

```
spark-submit \
    --conf spark.executorEnv.PYTHON_EGG_CACHE="./.python-eggs/" \
    --conf spark.executorEnv.PYTHON_EGG_DIR="./.python-eggs/" \
    --conf spark.driverEnv.PYTHON_EGG_CACHE="./.python-eggs/" \
    --conf spark.driverEnv.PYTHON_EGG_DIR="./.python-eggs/" \
```